# How do I split a string with '$' delimiter?

Tags: c#

I have this `FINAL PAYMENT $25` string on a MVC c# application.

I want to split into `FINAL PAYMENT` and `25`

I tried doing this

```
string s = "FINAL PAYMENT $25";
string[] str1 = s.Split('$');
//result: 25
```

How can I get the rest. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried `str1[0]`?

Comment: How can you get the rest what?  The split creates an array on the left and right of the split value.  So str1[0] is left of the $ and str1[1]  is value right of the $

Comment: Did you try it out in the debugger? What does `Split` return in your case? I guess you´ll find the answer yourself once you use the debugger.

Comment: The result of `s.Split('$')` is **not** 25

Comment: @TimSchmelter, it's what OP wants.

Comment: Remember, in C# array subscripts start at 0, not 1.

Comment: So basically you know to use `String.Split` but you had no idea what arrays are? Time to read a book  or at least the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2) method returns a string array, if you need both elements of this array,  Try:

```
string s = "FINAL PAYMENT $25";
string[] resArray =  s.Split('$');
var FPayment = resArray[0];
var second25= resArray[1];
```

Comment: Code only answers are not helpful, besides this does not even answer the question

Comment: Your edit _still_ does not answer the question

Comment: @maccettura - It seems to answer the question to me?

Comment: @Enigmativity Quote from the OP: `"I want to split into 'FINAL PAYMENT' and '25'"` -- This answer does not satisfy the question.  **EDIT:**  Now it does

Comment: <b>apomene's</b> solution works great. Thank you for your help! Just needed to fix the  missing open "[" in resArray 1].

Answer (score -1):

You can use indexOf instead of a Split

```
string s = "FINAL PAYMENT $25";
int index = s.IndexOf("$");
String final_pay = s.Substring(index + 1);
```

Comment: Even if you can do it it doesn't solve an issue because the question is unclear. `String.Split` works also. It especially doesn't answer the question if you take it's title into account.

Comment: Spliting "$" does not work with .split or even with Regex split. Now if he wants to use split, he can replace it by another "splitable" character and use it.

Comment: Sure it does: `"FINAL PAYMENT $25".Split('$')`. You can split by any character

Comment: @SnowDeveloper Why on earth would you expect `$` to not be a character you can split on?  What evidence do you have of this?  [I have](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vuoNkq) evidence to counter your statement...